# If I delete the files on my computer’s Dropbox folder does it delete them from Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I want to free up space on my computer but I still want to keep the files on Dropbox. If I delete them from my PC’s Dropbox folder do they get deleted off Dropbox as well?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the files get deleted from Dropbox as well. However, there are two possibilities to overcome this:

1. Set the Dropbox app to sync selectively and disable sync for that particular folder that you want to keep online, but delete its content offline.
2. Use the [restore](https://www.dropbox.com/help/40/en) feature for the deleted files.

   > If you want to restore any deleted files, keep in mind that Dropbox saves a history of all deleted and earlier versions of files for 30 days for all Dropbox accounts. If you purchase the Packrat add-on for your account, Dropbox will save your files for as long as you have the feature.

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/help/142) may help if you like option 1.