# Will deleting pictures from Dropbox online delete them from my PC's (and iPad's) folders?

Tags: dropbox

If I delete pictures from my Dropbox account, will it also delete them from Win7 folders and iPad Photostream?

Comment: Do note: Photo Stream is unrelated to Dropbox.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58229/if-i-delete-the-files-on-my-computers-dropbox-folder-does-it-delete-them-from-d?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

So long as the desktop/iPad is connected to your Dropbox account, yes, deleting them from Dropbox account online will delete them from your desktop/iPad.

Comment: Thanks much for replying to my question.  May I ask, how do I disconnect my desktop/Ipad from my Dropbox account?  Thanks, Howie

Comment: @Howie take a look at this - https://www.dropbox.com/help/25/en

Answer (score 1):

Deleting photos from Dropbox will delete it from any synced folders like those on your Windows machine.

It will not delete any photos from your iPhone/iPad albums or Photo Stream. In fact, as of iOS 7 no iOS App Store apps are able to delete photos from iOS devices because there is no public Apple API to do this.